# В чем причина проблемы

Tags: cs-cart, iphone-x

В чем может быть причина, при двойном клике на ссылки под-меню сайта cs-cart unitheme в смартфоне iPhone X раздел открывается, при одном клике ссылки не чувствительны

Answer (score 0):

В changelog видел или цс карта или ЮниТемы фикс этой проблемы, в последних обновах, за 1-3 месяца, вроде.